# What is Edward Scissorhands?

Tags: edward-scissorhands

Edwards Scissorhands was created by "The Inventor" as one of many machines. He is apparently upgradeable as the Inventor intended to change Edward's hands with normal ones.

[image: Edward Normalhands]

But we also see Edward not only eating food

[image: Edward Forkhands]

but drinking.

[image: Edward Drinkinghands]

The food/drink is not necessarily just passing through a robot body, as he becomes drunk and throws up.

**Is Edward a <del>time traveling</del> robot? An oddly upgradeable human? Something else entirely?**

Comment: Yes, he is a time travelling robot - Rondo

Comment: He's a goth cyborg.

Comment: Why should he be a machine? I perceived him more as something like a Frankenstein monster.

Comment: "*Because Edward is **not human, and not a robot**, I didn't think that he would talk a lot. He would cut through everything and have the most honest, pure answer with all the clarity in the world."* - [Jonny Depp: Rolling Stone](http://www.deppimpact.com/edward.php)

Comment: Some answers here on movies:SE - [Why was Edward given scissors instead of hands?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/18380/why-was-edward-given-scissors-instead-of-hands)

Comment: [Paging John Siracusa](https://www.theincomparable.com/robot/).

Answer (score 3):

As described on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Scissorhands) he is an artificial man, an unfinished creation who has scissors for hands.

That would mean that he is built to be as similar to real man as possible. I presume he was intended to be something like Data from Star Trek just not that advanced.

Answer (score -4):

It's possible that he was a congenital amputee resulting from a partially failed attempt at lab growing a fetus. Due to the failure of the experiment the program was shut down and the sole surviving subject ordered destroyed so that there wouldn't be any evidence. The "inventor," seeing the boy as not only the culmination of his life's work, but also as his own child, couldn't allow the child to be killed and instead kidnapped him and disappeared. Considering Edward appears around 20, the inventor was already advanced in years at this point. Having focused primarily on bio-chemistry and little on engineering, the inventor would have had to learn an entirely new field of science without the luxury of proper schooling, the internet, or youth.

Comment: This seems like a simple fan-fiction. can you provide any canonical evidence for this?

Comment: There's no canonical answer to the question that was originally asked, even the answer on the wiki is conjecture, and even then doesn't really answer the question other than to say that he was created artificially. Many would argue that replicants from blade runner are "artificial people" simply because they are made in a lab, when they are in fact regular humans capable of everything a regular human is capable of.